# Horizontal aligning of labels, buttons and textboxes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am working in asp.net webform and Bootstrap 5.2, I created a row containing a label, multiline textbox and two other buttons. When i used the class as row align-items-center, everything is aligned, but the issue is the label and the two textboxes are dropping by 30px from the center horizontal . Why? i have to give an additional margin-bottom-30px to align them at the center? Please guide me.
`

```
            <div align="center" class="container  ">
                <div class="row align-items-center  " style="width: 70%; ">
                    <div class="col-2 rta   " style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text=" Comments:" ></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 " >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomments" CssClass="form-control dkborder" runat="server" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3   "style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                        <asp:Button ID="BaupleViewReport" runat="server" Style="position: relative;" CssClass="mybutton" Text="View Report" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3   "style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                        <asp:Button ID="DownloadDrawing" runat="server" Style="position: relative;" CssClass="mybutton" Text="Download Drawing" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

`

The 4 components were not perfectly aligned horizontally and i had to give a margin bottom of 30px to align them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the elements to be aligned so that they are centered in the grid, you can use the `.justify-content-center` class on the `.row` element.

Comment: They are clinging to the top, can you guide me further

Comment: is it like this?    <style>
        .row {
            justify-content: center                
        }
    </style>

Comment: it's like `<div class="row justify-content-center" style="width: 70%; ">`, You got more informations this way : [Flex bootscrap 5.2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/)

Comment: Thanks , it did not work either, all the four elements were sticking like magnet to the top.